# how to set the response writer in XPages to UTF-8?

Tags: xpages

I have a Porblem an I hope that someone could help me.

I'm reading some values from an notes View by using the following Code

```
...
ViewEntryCollection vec = MyView.getAllEntries();
ViewEntry viewentry = vec.getFirstEntry();
while (viewentry != null) {
     row = new Vector<String>();
 Vector rowvec = viewentry.getColumnValues();
...
```

then I build an HTML table with the values
this works fine my Problem is the the Response to an Xpage

```
public void getHTMLStream(DominoFacesContext FacesContext, String HTMLstr) {
     ExternalContext con = FacesContext.getExternalContext();
     XspHttpServletResponse response = (XspHttpServletResponse)    
     con.getResponse();
     byte[] content;
     try {
          ServletOutputStream writer = response.getOutputStream();

      // setting response headers for browser
      response.setContentType("application/html");
      response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myhtml.html\"");

          content = HTMLstr.getBytes();
      writer.write(content);

      writer.flush();
      writer.close();

      FacesContext.responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If in the HTMLstr are German Umlauts like ä,Ö,Ü the "writer" converts them to some stange signs. Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can set charset in the contenttype by the following statement
>
> **response.setContentType("application/html;charset=UTF-8");**

Answer (score 1):

Another options would be to just use the correct method

```
response.setCharacterEncoding()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
content = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(content,"UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still needs this. PrintWriter uses Encoding from xsp properties, so just make sure you have xsp.html.page.encoding=utf-8